# How to convert from a quadratic form to canonical, when there's no squared unknown?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, quadrics

I already know that this is hyperbolic paraboloid, but I can't turn it into a canonical equation:

$ z = xy $

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
xy= \frac{1}{4}((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Rotating $xy$ by $\pi/4$ changes to $x^2-y^2$.